# .htaccess rewrite rule handled correctly

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to redirect rewrite `/zp-core/admin.php` to `admin` but somehow I can't get it to work.

I've added this rule to my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/admin$ /zp-core/admin.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^albums/?(.+/?)?$ $1 [R=301,L] 
...
# Catch-all - everything else gets handled in PHP for compatibility.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$                        index.php?album=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The third rule should do it, but somehow it doesn't. In the end it falls back on the catch all rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "rewrite **A** to **B**", usually, "A" is what the user types and "B" is where you want him to get.

If A='`/admin`' and B='`/zp-core/admin.php`' then the first rule is ok, if you remove other rules, it will work.

The problem is - apache looks into .htaccess on every request, including sub-requests, and your redirect does a sub-request... So it does not match the first rule anymore, but then comes the catch-all rule, and it is a match again (you'll see that `$_GET["album"]` will be `/zp-core/admin.php` when hitting index.php on such request.

What you need to do is to add `RewriteCond` either checking that the uri is not `/zp-core/admin.php` OR that you're not in sub-request...

Either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zp-core/admin.php$
```

OR:

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} !=true
```